# Compute the probability that a hand of 13 cards contains the ace and king of at least one suit.

Tags: probability

I tried this.

All possible outcomes are ${52 \choose 13}$.

Favourable outcomes are where I have the ace and king of one suit and any other 11 cards, the ace and king of two suits and any other 9 cards, etc.

This equals ${4 \choose 1}{50 \choose 11} + {4 \choose 2}{48 \choose 9} + {4 \choose 3}{46 \choose 7} + {4 \choose 4}{44 \choose 5}$. But this is wrong somewhere, and doesn’t match the answer.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You are double-counting. I'd use inclusion/exclusion.

Comment: Okay, I got the answer. But can you help me to see what I was double counting?

Comment: So, for example. In the first term, I’m choosing any one suit and drawing the ace and king from this suit. Then, since I’m choosing the remaining 11 cards from the 50 cards, which include other aces and kings, I may also get cases where I have more than one pair of an ace and a king. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are counting hands with AK of Heart and AK of diamonds twice already in the first term, and for a third time in the second.